# How do create a borderless table with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

I simply want to align some text and spans easily. So I made a table, thinking that I could somehow tell the code to not draw any lines.

Here is my example table:

```
        <table class="table">
          <tbody id="checkbox_list">
        <tr  style='border:none' >
          <td  style='border:none' > Something <td>
          <td  style='border:none' > <span class="label label-default" style="background-color:#000000;width:35px;height:20px;display:inline-block;"><td>
        </tr>
        <tr  style='border:none' >
          <td  style='border:none' > Something <td>
          <td  style='border:none' > <span class="label label-default" style="background-color:#000000;width:35px;height:20px;display:inline-block;"><td>
        </tr>           
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is what it shows me

[image]

Anyway that I can get rid of those pesky lines besides the black box?

Comment: No `td` is closing in the above HTML

Comment: Can't you just use the `borderless` class on the `<table>` element? And you also need to close your `<td>`s.

Comment: The td thing was the problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the td properly.  Use the following CSS to solve you problem.

```
.table tr, .table td {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is adding some border in the tables. Add this to your custom CSS:

**CSS**

```
.table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > thead > tr > th {
    border: none;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g92x5n8s/2/)**

> This CSS must percede the bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.table > tbody > tr > td{
    border: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asokvtg4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4xdE/319/)**

```
.table.no-border tr td, .table.no-border tr th {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table no-border">
          <tbody id="checkbox_list">
        <tr>
          <td> ... <td>
          <td > ... <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td >  .. <td>
          <td > .. <td>
        </tr>           
          </tbody>
        </table>
```